# Enable PHP Blowfish on OSX

Tags: php, macos, mamp, bcrypt, password-hash

I've recently moved to OS X 10.7 as my development machine, running MAMP Pro 2.0.5.
The encryption library we're using uses blowfish by default, but does not appear to be available on this platform config. All our existing data is encrypted using blowfish, so now I can't deal with it.

I've search the MAMP manuals, and found no reference to it, and everything else I've found relates to mcrypt being available or not, but not the encryption algorithm.

How can I enable blowfish, or am I totally missing something with the concept? Unfortunately I'm developing for PHP < 5.3, so native support isn't available.

Comment: what encryption library?

Comment: phppass http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: ok, that is not encryption it is hashing, and it is just the bcrypt password hash method. Are you unable to build phpass on Lion?

Comment: It's just flat PHP, it doesn't build. It relies on what's available on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure PHP class that can be used on any operating system running PHP including OSX. [PHP 5 blowfish encryption class](https://github.com/themattharris/PHP-Blowfish/blob/master/blowfish.php) You just need to include it into your source and call its methods where needed.